# Symmetry of colliding bodies

Tags: energy, momentum, symmetry

If two objects of equal masses come together at equal speed, they will move apart at that same speed, as a matter of symmetry. What is the symmetry being talked about?

(The text is about elastic collision from Feynman's lectures.)

Comment: Think about your statement in the context of a train and a bicycle heading one towards the other at the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a space transformation symmetry which leads to the conservation of momentum. Since there is no acceleration means there is no external force and consequently, energy is conserved. Using conservation of momentum and energy we find that the outgoing speeds are the same. 
Basically, the underlying symmetries are time and space translations.

Comment: why would you assume the masses are the same?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero masses are indeed same (according to the book).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero He's my reasoning: 1) It's Feynman, hence it is correct. It has to be equal mass to be correct, hence: they are equal mass. Q.E.D.